# javascript - innerHTML with fade in

Tags: javascript, css

With the following line of code:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
```

Is it possible to add the .fadeIn("slow" ) function? I would like the new text to fade in.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I don't think so, just javascript.

Comment: But `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML` will return you String object. which will not have access to the function whatsoever so you cannot chain the `.fadeIn()` method. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: Is it possible... yes. How to do it... that depends on what you use, how do you want to make it, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: OK. I'm going to try something with this instead:

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    ///////
});});

Comment: The only way to use the `fadeIn('slow')` function is to be using the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library.

Answer (score 7):

Do it with js+CSS.
With a CSS transition it will fade in.

You need to have the font-color set to background-color.
First change content,
then change color to normal font color.

Your js:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = "#333333";
```

Your CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: color 2s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: the tag doesnt mention css.Be specific while you answer

Comment: As you can read in his comments, the author doesnt know himself if he uses jquery or just javascript, so i think he is not aware that there's a possibility with CSS for that. Thats because i want to help him and used my brain. Dont tell others what to answer, without making it better this is just bad behaviour.

Comment: cari i didnt mean to be rude.I know u helped the person.Cheers:)

Comment: This does not work on multiple selections. Ie, if the selection changes, the colour does not fade out.

Comment: of course not, since it was asked for getElementById, and there is only 1 element in every DOM that should have the ID "myDiv". for multiple elements you need to use getElementsByClassName and loop over the result. or just use jquery^^

Answer (score 1):

Ended up just doing this:

```
$("div.col-lg-6").replaceWith(function() {
return $(txt).hide().fadeIn(1000);});
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why did you say you're not using it in your comments? Just use `$('mydiv').text(txt).fadeIn('slow');` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but you could do it like this: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/LVxxjM

Where we use CSS transitions for the purpose.

```
<button class='add'>Add text</button>
<button class='clear'>Clear text</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

and:

```
#myDiv {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1000ms;
}

#myDiv.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and:

```
var myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");

document.querySelector(".add").addEventListener('click', function() {
  myDiv.textContent = "Fade magic";
  myDiv.classList.add('show');
}, false);

document.querySelector(".clear").addEventListener('click', function() {
  myDiv.classList.remove('show');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS

```
#mydiv {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

In JS

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity= "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to worry about fading in/out the `innerHTML` property.  Instead, wrap the innerHTML in a `span` tag (or, alternatively, a `div` tag), and then simply fade that element in and out.

Here it is with a 1,000 millisecond delay:

```js
const fadetime = 1000;

function fadeInElement(element) {
  element.style.removeProperty('display');

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.remove('fade');
  }, 10);

  return true;
}

function fadeOutElement(element) {
  element.classList.add('fade');

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  }, fadetime);

  return true;
}

var buttondisplay = false;

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if(buttondisplay) {
    fadeOutElement(document.getElementById('button-text-2'));
    setTimeout(function() {
      fadeInElement(document.getElementById('button-text-1'));
    }, fadetime);
  } else {
    fadeOutElement(document.getElementById('button-text-1'));
    setTimeout(function() {
      fadeInElement(document.getElementById('button-text-2'));
    }, fadetime);
  }
  buttondisplay = !buttondisplay;
});
```

```css
.fadeable {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
    <span id="button-text-1" class="fadeable">First Text</span>
    <span id="button-text-2" class="fadeable fade" style="display:none;">Second text!</span>
</button>
```